# Nested SMARTY objects accessing variables across instances

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I'm trying to mesh together several stages of templating in a smooth maintainable way.  I have an outer page which has a smarty object instantiated and that includes another php page which instantiates a different smarty object.  My question is if there is any way to assign a variable in the outer instance and have it accessible in the inner instance.

Schematically I'm calling page.php:

```
<?php
$tpl = new Smarty();
$tpl->assign("a","Richard");
$tpl->register_function('load_include', 'channel_load_include');
$tpl->display("outer_template.tpl");
function channel_load_include($params, &$smarty) {
    include(APP_DIR . $params["page"]);
}
?>
```

outer_template.tpl:

```
<div> {load_include page="/otherpage.php"} </div>
```

otherpage.php:

```
<?php
$tpl2=new Smarty();
$tpl2->assign("b","I");
$tpl2->display("inner_template.tpl");
?>
```

inner_template.tpl:

```
<span id="pretentiousReference"> "Richard loves {$a}, that is I am {$b}" </span>
```

And I'm seeing: "Richard loves , that is I am I"

Is there a way to access the outer instance's variable from the inner instance or should I just dump it in `$_SESSION` and pull it with a `{php}` tag?  Obviously my application is a tad more complicated but this exposes what I believe to be the core problem.

Comment: Don't know if it fits your need but you could maybe have several stages of smarty rendering, like {$a} and <@$b@>

Comment: Another idea is to use the {include} plugin to include a subtemplate instead of a sub-php ; http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl ; they share assignation variables

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER, that would work in the simple case that I've shown here but would require impractically large rewrites for my real app.  I need a solution that leaves the overall hierarchy intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build chains of smarty / template / data instances to make data accessible to different instances.

Assigning a Smarty instance as the parent of another one:

```
$outer = new Smarty();
$outer->assign('outer', 'hello');
$inner = new Smarty();
$inner->parent = $outer;
$inner->assign('inner', 'world');
$inner->display('eval:{$outer} {$inner}');
```

alternatively you could pull your data out:

```
$data = new Smarty_Data();
$data->assign('outer', 'hello');
$outer = new Smarty();
$outer->parent = $data;
$inner = new Smarty();
$inner->parent = $data;
$inner->assign('inner', 'world');
$inner->display('eval:{$outer} {$inner}');
```

both output "hello world"